# how can i insert data from a text file into a database using shell

Tags: mysql, database, shell

i have a scenario where i have a database table that has 3 columns instance name and version which has to contain data of jenkins instance and the plugins installed along with version...and i have a text file that has the details of name and version and the code that i have to insert the name and version is

```
input_file="test.txt"
cat $input_file | while read plugin version; do
        echo "INSERT INTO table_name (version,pluginname)  VALUES('$version' ,'$pluginname');"
done | mysql -user_root -db_password dbname;
```

Now i am stuck here how can i insert the instance value in the database.
the text file contains data for all instances, i.e the plugin name and version which i got by parsing the JSON API

```
curl -u user:<api-token> -s -k "https://<jenkins instance>/pluginManager/api/json?depth=1" | jq '.plugins[]|{version,longName}' -c  | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/,/:/g' | cut -d ":" -f2,4 > test.txt
```

since the data for plugin name and version is picked up by the text file i can do that but i am not sure how to add data in the instance column.there are 6 instances to be added in total.
A sample of that database table would be

```
instance     plugin  version
instance1    plugin1  ver 1
instance1    plugin2  ver2
.....
instance2    plugin1  ver1
instance2    plugin2  ver2
......
......
instance3    plugin1   ver1
instance3    plugin2   ver2
.....
```

this has to be done for all 6 instances

how can i do this.
Thanks in advance for answering

Comment: If the input file doesn't contain the instance names, only the plug-in and version, then where would they come from?

Comment: that is what i am trying to find out the solution for

Comment: We cannot pull the instance names out of thin air.

Comment: yeah i do have an instance list..but that can be added in one more text file...there are 6 jenkins instances in total

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have multiple Jenkins instances to call. If you have a list of their names, then you can loop over that list, call `curl` to get the list of plugins and their versions and generate the SQL statements, wrapping your original script:

```
for instance in $instance_list; do
    curl ... | jq ... | ... > plugins.txt
    while read plugin version; do
        echo "INSERT INTO table_name (instance, version,pluginname)  VALUES('$instance', '$version' ,'$pluginname');"
    done < plugins.txt | mysql -user_root -db_password dbname
done
```

Comment: will try this code and let you know how this works..thanks